# Populating comboBox with the first column of layer table attribute using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, combo-box

I am new to Python and QGIS.
I want to populate the comboBox with the first column of the table attribute of the park's layer

Code:

```
 #Populate park's comboBox
        park = layers[0].layer()
        park.startEditing()
        for p in park.getFeatures():
                self.dlg.comboBox_2.addItem(p.attributes()[0])
```

Error:

> 2022-01-03T01:39:23     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/ADS/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\urban_parks\urban_parks.py",
> line 217, in run
>
> self.dlg.comboBox_2.addItem(p.attributes()[0])
> TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
> addItem(self, str, userData: Any = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
>
> addItem(self,
> QIcon, str, userData: Any = None): argument 1 has unexpected type
> 'int'

Comment: if you're just going to enumerate the park layer's features to populate the comboBox you don't need to call `startEditing`. In fact, you probably should avoid it.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the feature attributes which you are trying to add to your combo box are evidently of an integer datatype. The `addItem()` method of `QComboBox` expects a string argument.

Therefore, you need to cast the attribute value argument to a string:

```py
...
for p in park.getFeatures():
    self.dlg.comboBox_2.addItem(str(p.attributes()[0]))
...
```

Comment: You will also need to remember that when you fetch the selected value from the combo box, it will be returned as a string. To be consistent with the type in the attribute, you will want to convert it back to an int using the `int()` function.